# Give jQuery content slider percentage width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm using the [Lightweight jQuery Content Slider](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/12/lightest-jquery-content-slider-ever-made-380-bytes/) and trying to figure out how I can make the width percentage-based instead of pixel-based to fit into a responsive design. Here is the code for the slider:

HTML

```
<div id="button">
         <a class="button1 active" rel="1" href="#"></a>
         <a class="button2" rel="2" href="#"></a>
         <a class="button3" rel="3" href="#"></a>
    </div> <!-- end of div button-->

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="myslide">
        <div class="cover">

            <div class="mystuff">
                some slide content
            </div>
            <div class="mystuff">
                some slide content
            </div>
            <div class="mystuff">
                some slide content
            </div>

        </div> <!-- end of div cover -->
    </div>  <!-- end of div myslide -->
```

CSS

```
#myslide {width:160px;overflow:hidden;position: relative;height:170px;margin-bottom:20px}

    #myslide .cover{
        width:480px; /*------- class mystuff width * number of mystuff divs (160 * 3 = 480)---------- */
        position: absolute;
        height:160px;
    }

    #myslide .mystuff {width:160px;float:left;padding:20px 0;}

    .button1,.button2,.button3{background:#999;padding:6px;display:block;float:left;margin-right:5px;}
    .active{background:#111;padding:6px;display:block;float:left;outline:none;}
    .clear{clear:both;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#button a').click(function(){
        var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-160*(parseInt(integer)-1)})  /*----- Width of div mystuff (here 160) ------ */
        $('#button a').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
                $(this).addClass('active')}
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tweaks here and there.

**First replace

```
left:-160*(parseInt(integer)-1)
```

with

```
left: -($('#myslide').width()) * (parseInt(integer) - 1)
```

#### and then a few CSS changes like

```
#myslide .cover {
    width:300%;
}
#myslide .mystuff {
    width:33.3%;
}
```

Now you only need to change the width of `#myslide` to anything that you want

```
#myslide {
    width: 160px;
}
```

Here is the working copy - http://jsfiddle.net/E2xp4/

Comment: Wow dude, great work! Thank you. Do you have any idea why sometimes, when you go to the second slide, the very edge of the text from the next slide shows?

Comment: @BrandonMcPeak That's because of using 33.3% when you are looking it on a large screen, even that 1% will be like a lot of pixels due to which we are able to see some part from the next slide.

One workaround would be to set `display:none` to all the slides on the right side of the active slide.